# How to remove option for Ordnance Survey in Bing Maps V8 Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I would like to remove the Ordnance Survey map type option in my Bing Maps v8 javascript map.

I'm looking through the interactive SDK, and there is an option to [remove Streetside](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#disableStreetside+JS), so I'm hoping there is a way to disable the Ordnance Survey maps as well.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time anyone has asked for this, however there is a fairly easy way to remove it from the dropdown list of options. The [map options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712646.aspx) has a property called `supportedMapTypes` which you can pass in an array of [map types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712700.aspx), and it will only display those as options in the dropdown. Here is an example to limit it to road and aerial.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;

    function GetMap()
    {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
            supportedMapTypes: [
                Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial
            ]
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I've pasted your code into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fletch1/5yyxL77h/), but the Ordnance Survey map option is still shown.  I've read the documentation, but I'm having trouble spotting what's not right.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: hmmm.... this looks like a bug. Will log this with the team. Another option is to add "&setMkt=en-US" to the map script URL.

Comment: Thanks, the additional parameter on the query string works brilliantly.  We will go with that for now :).  Thanks for your help!